# Generate caffemodel file

Tags: python, lua, protocol-buffers, caffe, torch

I am using both Torch and Caffe for deep learning. I wonder if there is a way to output nn model into caffemodel file. It may involve protobuf, which I am not familiar with.

It is kinda easy for the other way, where there are [libraries](https://github.com/szagoruyko/loadcaffe) to read caffemodel file into torch.

Comment: I am not familiar with torch. but there is a straight forward way to read caffe models to python. Would you be able to take data from python into torch?

Comment: @Shai I indeed can play with h5 and t7 files for conversion.

Comment: are there layers that exists in t7 and not in caffe? I suspect there are... what about these types of layers?

Comment: @Shai Don't think so. I think the structure should be all the same if they are based on the same model.

Comment: you might find the links in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33847461/1714410) useful.